# Can I prevent my S6 from reducing brightness at 5% battery?

Tags: settings, battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s-6, screen-brightness

My Samsung Galaxy S6 with Android 6.0.1 always dims the screen when hitting 5% remaining battery. This is very bad in bright sunlight because the screen gets so dark that it's impossible to use the phone and pure guesswork to brighten it again. This “feature“ seems to override both auto and manual brightness setting. It also happens irrespective of power saving mode on/off. How can I stop it from doing this?

Comment: Try [Macrodroid](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/158165/131553) automation app.  *Trigger:* battery <6℅ *Action:* brightness - adjust to desired level *Constraints:* power disconnected. This should solve your problem. Not posting as an answer as I don't have a device on Lollipop. Once you confirm it works, will post as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That feature is built into the kernel. You would need an unlocked boot loader and a custom recovery. Then you could flash a different kernel or custom rom to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for Power Saver Mode. This is under the *Settings > Battery*.
There is usually an option to turn on Power Saver Mode altogether or adjust what it does.

See

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00038729/

Comment: Thanks, but this is done by my phone no matter if power saving is on or off. So disabling power saving mode does not stop the automatism that the screen gets dimmed to minimum when hitting 5% battery.

Answer (score 0):

Samsung Galaxy Phones do dim their phones once it reaches the low level of battery. You may try this: http://www.samsung.com/ie/support/skp/faq/1056771

Comment: This setting does not exist on the S6, unfortunately.